# Error creating Glue connection with DocumentDB

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, aws-glue, aws-documentdb

I have created a connection in Glue with a DocumentDB cluster. The cluster is running and I can connect from my laptop and also from AWS athena to run Athena queries over it. The connection URL in Glue follows this format:

> mongodb://host:27017/database

In the connection creation I have tried enabling and disabling the SSL connection option:
[image]

Also I have disable in the cluster the TLS and rebooted the database. Every time I test the connection with Glue I get this error:

> Check that your connection definition references your Mongo database with correct URL syntax, username, and password.
> Exiting with error code 30

Also I have tried setting the user and password in the URL but I get the same error.

How can I solve this?

Thanks!!!

Comment: How exactly do you try to connect? What is your code or settings in glue console?

Comment: I have set the URL as I mention above, the VPC  and subnet where the database is running, the user and password and a security group

Comment: But is it for glue crawler, job? Sadly your question lacks details and is unclear.

Comment: The question is clear. I have a documentDB database and I'm triying to create a glue connection. In the glue service in the panel there is a section called Connections. I need this connection created in Glue to use in different glue jobs.

Comment: @Shadowtrooper Could you share the complete connection options you're setting?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have solved the problem. Disabling TLS on DocumnetDB and in the Glue connection works. I have to find the way to make it working with TLS enabled.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, does the "database" actually exists in DocumentDB cluster? Make sure you select the right VPC for Glue, has to be the same as DocumentDB. When using the Test Connection option, one of the security groups has to have an allow all rule, or the source security group in your inbound rule can be restricted to the same security group.
This [blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/building-aws-glue-spark-etl-jobs-using-amazon-documentdb-with-mongodb-compatibility-and-mongodb/) post has some good info on how to setup a Glue connection to MongoDB/DocumentDB.