# Glue connection with DocumentDB with ssl enabled get timeout

Tags: ssl, aws-documentdb

My Question is related to this thread : [Error creating Glue connection with DocumentDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73021449/error-creating-glue-connection-with-documentdb)

Glue service with SSL enabled document db connection is always timing out. when i disable cert ,my connection is working fine.

I am not sure where to pass the SSL cert when i create a documentdb connection in glue.

As per aws document : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/connection-properties.html#connection-properties-SSL . they support monogodb . but i am not able to find any instruction to pass SSL cert. Appreciate any inputs!

I tried to AWS glue service to connect documentdb with SSL enabled. I got time out message and am not sure SSL cert option is supported for documentdb